# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reader'

Tags: python, csv

Couldn't get what wrong in the code, as `csv` module has a `csv.reader()` function as per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html). But I am still getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    read = csv.reader(csv, delimiter = ',')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

My code:

```
import csv

with open('test_csv.csv') as csv:
    read = csv.reader(csv, delimiter = ',')
    for row in read:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You re-bound the name `csv` in the `as` target:

```
with open('test_csv.csv') as csv:
```

This masks the module name, so `csv.reader` is resolved *on the file object*.

Use a different target:

```
with open('test_csv.csv') as csvfile:
    read = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in read:
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, changing the line into "with open('test_csv.csv') as csvfile" has worked. It has resulted in conflict and hence the error.