# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reader' [Worse Problem]

Tags: python, csv, python-3.9

I was writing my code for a calendar with events, but it keeps giving me this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Local Drive/Documents/Other/calendar_if_it_works.py", line 42, in <module>
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

I know that there are other people with the problem, like [Seperate File Named csv.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341363/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-reader) and [The name of the code is csv problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523325/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-reader). But when I try those, they don't work.

And here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar
import csv
import itertools as itt
from operator import itemgetter

def unique_rows(rows):
    for key, group in itt.groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(0)):
        yield (key,) + tuple(itt.chain.from_iterable(r[1:] for r in group))
 
def main():
    with open('csv_file.csv') as ifh, open('output.csv', 'w') as ofh:
        rd = csv.reader(ifh)
        wt = csv.writer(ofh)
        wt.writerows(unique_rows(rd))
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

records = {}
mtoflag = False
line = 0
ncol=0
with open('output.csv', 'r') as csv:
     first_line = csv.readline()
     your_data = csv.readlines()
for i in range(len(your_data)):
    ncol = your_data[i].count(',') + 1
    print(your_data[i])
    print(ncol)
    if ncol > 2:
        mtoflag = True
        line = your_data[i]
        break

print(mtoflag)
print(line)
print("Column:", ncol)

with open('output.csv', mode='r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, deliminter=",")
    for rows in reader:
        if mtoflag == True:
            if rows == line:
                records[rows[0]] = list(rows[1], rows[columns-1])
                print(records)
        else:
            records[rows[0]] = rows[1]


print(records)

# creating an object of tkinter

tkobj = Tk()

# setting up the geomentry

tkobj.title("Calendar picker")
#creating a calender object

tkc = Calendar(tkobj,selectmode = "day",year=2022,month=4,date=1)

#display on main window
tkc.pack(pady=40)

# getting date from the calendar 

def fetch_date():
    edate = tkc.get_date()
    if edate == "":
        edate="None Selected"
    date.config(text = "Selected Date is: " + edate)
    recval = []
    recval.append(records.get(edate))
    print("Record Values:", recval)
    events.delete(0, END)
    events.insert(END, recval)

#add button to load the date clicked on calendar

but = Button(tkobj,text="Select Date",command=fetch_date)
#displaying button on the main display
but.pack()
#Label for showing date on main display
date = Label(tkobj,text="",bg='black',fg='white')
date.pack(pady=20)
# Event Label indicator
eventind = Label(tkobj, text="Events:", bg='black', fg='white')
eventind.pack()
# Event Listbox for showing events
events = Listbox(tkobj, width=34, height=20)
events.pack()
#starting the object
tkobj.mainloop()
```

I checked csv.**file** but there was no other file besides the library.
I also checked the name, as you can see; but I don't know the problem.
Do you know any ways of fixing it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answers your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523325/attributeerror-io-textiowrapper-object-has-no-attribute-reader?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your code gives no error.

But it gives you an error if you call the `main` function in last.

This error is because you make a variable `csv`

Try this code.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar
import csv
import itertools as itt
from operator import itemgetter

def unique_rows(rows):
    for key, group in itt.groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(0)):
        yield (key,) + tuple(itt.chain.from_iterable(r[1:] for r in group))
 
def main():
    with open('csv_file.csv') as ifh, open('output.csv', 'w') as ofh:
        rd = csv.reader(ifh)
        wt = csv.writer(ofh)
        wt.writerows(unique_rows(rd))

records = {}
mtoflag = False
line = 0
ncol=0
with open('output.csv', 'r') as csv_: # changing the variable name
     first_line = csv_.readline()
     your_data = csv_.readlines()
for i in range(len(your_data)):
    ncol = your_data[i].count(',') + 1
    print(your_data[i])
    print(ncol)
    if ncol > 2:
        mtoflag = True
        line = your_data[i]
        break

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful, but now the CSV reader gives you empty map `{}`.